# ggplot or plot random sample of data

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way to run a random sample of that data I want to plot in one swoop?

```
ggplot()+
  labs(y="Monthly Pay $", title="Monthly Pay per Pay Instance by Employee")+
   geom_line(aes(y=MonthlyPay, x=PayInstance, group=EMPLID),
   data = linetechanalysisTermed)
```

I have 7,759 in this population and myplot is completely unreadable (I thought about altering the axis but I don't think it will help with such a large population).

Comment: Please don't tag your question `rstudio` unless you the problem has something to do with RStudio, e.g., the problem happens in RStudio but not in other code editors (e.g., RGui, command line, ...).

Comment: Replace `data = linetechanalysisTermed` with `data = linetechanalysisTermed[sample(nrow(linetechanalysisTermed), 100),]` to plot 100 observations (use `set.seed` for reproducibility).

Comment: 10-4 Gregor, thanks lmo